# Google maps tool tip not working full screen mode

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using following site example to display tooltip on hover polygon.

http://philmap.000space.com/gmap-api/poly-hov.html?i=1

In normal view tooltip working as expected on hover. But in full screen mode tooltip not showing working. tried to fixed with z-index, set tooltip div position relative but not not working.

here is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapD4"), {
        zoom: 14,
        center: {
            lat: parseFloat(6.890132), lng: parseFloat(79.87557)
        },
});

var data_layer_1 = new google.maps.Data({ map: map });

data_layer_1.loadGeoJson('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Thanushkajayasinghe/D4Ward/main/Kirula.geojson');

data_layer_1.setStyle({
        strokeColor: '#8854d0',
        fillColor: '#8854d0',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillOpacity: 0.7
});

//Tooltip data_layer_1 click
google.maps.event.addListener(data_layer_1, 'click', function (e) {

        var district = e.feature.j.CMC_Dis;
        var ward = e.feature.j.CMC_Ward;

        loadTooltip(district, ward);
});

function loadTooltip(district, ward) {
        $.ajax({
            url: LoadDisMapData,
            type: 'POST',
            data: { district: district, ward: ward },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {

                tooltip.show("Ward: <span style='font-weight: bold'>" + ward + "</span><br/>\
                                Population: <span style='font-weight: bold'>" + data.sumPopulation.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + "</span><br/>\
                                PCR Done: <span style='font-weight: bold'>" + data.pcrDoneCount.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + "</span><br/>\
                                Positive: <span style='font-weight: bold'>" + data.positiveCount.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + "</span><br/>\
                                Deaths: <span style='font-weight: bold'>" + data.deathsCount.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + "</span><br/>");
            }
        });
    }

   google.maps.event.addListener(data_layer_1, 'mouseout', function (e) {
        tooltip.hide();
    });

var tooltip = function () {
    var id = 'tt';
    var top = 3;
    var left = 3;
    var maxw = 300;
    var speed = 10;
    var timer = 20;
    var endalpha = 95;
    var alpha = 0;
    var tt, t, c, b, h;
    var ie = document.all ? true : false;
    return {
        show: function (v, w) {
            if (tt == null) {
                tt = document.createElement('div');
                tt.setAttribute('id', id);
                t = document.createElement('div');
                t.setAttribute('id', id + 'top');
                c = document.createElement('div');
                c.setAttribute('id', id + 'cont');
                b = document.createElement('div');
                b.setAttribute('id', id + 'bot');
                tt.appendChild(t);
                tt.appendChild(c);
                tt.appendChild(b);
                document.body.appendChild(tt);
                tt.style.opacity = 0;
                tt.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=0)';
                document.onmousemove = this.pos;
            }
            tt.style.display = 'block';
            c.innerHTML = v;
            tt.style.width = w ? w + 'px' : 'auto';
            if (!w && ie) {
                t.style.display = 'none';
                b.style.display = 'none';
                tt.style.width = tt.offsetWidth;
                t.style.display = 'block';
                b.style.display = 'block';
            }
            if (tt.offsetWidth > maxw) { tt.style.width = maxw + 'px' }
            h = parseInt(tt.offsetHeight) + top;
            clearInterval(tt.timer);
            tt.timer = setInterval(function () { tooltip.fade(1) }, timer);
        },
        pos: function (e) {
            var u = ie ? event.clientY + document.documentElement.scrollTop : e.pageY;
            var l = ie ? event.clientX + document.documentElement.scrollLeft : e.pageX;
            tt.style.top = (u - h) + 'px';
            tt.style.left = (l + left) + 'px';
        },
        fade: function (d) {
            var a = alpha;
            if ((a != endalpha && d == 1) || (a != 0 && d == -1)) {
                var i = speed;
                if (endalpha - a < speed && d == 1) {
                    i = endalpha - a;
                } else if (alpha < speed && d == -1) {
                    i = a;
                }
                alpha = a + (i * d);
                tt.style.opacity = alpha * .01;
                tt.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + alpha + ')';
            } else {
                clearInterval(tt.timer);
                if (d == -1) { tt.style.display = 'none' }
            }
        },
        hide: function () {
            clearInterval(tt.timer);
            tt.timer = setInterval(function () { tooltip.fade(-1) }, timer);
        }
    };
}();
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It doesn't look like the posted code is the *minimal* code needed to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that only elements inside the target element are shown in fullscreen.

So you need to replace this line

```
document.body.appendChild(tt);
```

with

```
document.getElementById('map_canvas').firstChild.appendChild(tt);
```